# How to insert into multiple databases in one stored procedure call

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a table that stores connection string to other databases.I have a common table among all my databases that I would like to insert data given the connection string. Using linq to sql I would like to know if it it possible to do multiple inserts into different databases in one stored procedure call.

I have tried the below I get no error message but data is not committed to he DB. Is this even possible? if so how can I achieve that

```
   private bool addUserToSelectedPortals(string Connectionstring, string accountIdList, int? logAccount, string userName, string logUserName, string moduleName, bool isLastUsed, bool isDefault, bool isDebugUser, ref string retMsg)
    {
          int? result =0;

          using (var context = new UserCreateDALDataContext(Connectionstring))
              {

               result = (context.adm_InsAccountUser(accountIdList, logAccount, userName, logUserName, moduleName, isLastUsed, isDefault, isDebugUser, ref retMsg));
               if(result = 0)
               { 
                  return false
               }
               else
                  return false;                                        
              }              

    }
```

Comment: I'd use database triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the thing is I read the connections based on the user selection dropdown. So i am not inserting to all database all the time.